# unable to fetch department column value in pl-sql developer

Tags: plsql

what to add so that i can fetch department column value

```
WHERE C1.CODE_ID(+) = ALLRESULT.BANK_CODE 
AND C1.CODE_CATEGORY = 'BANK' 
AND C2.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = ALLRESULT.DEPT_ID
AND C2.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = 'DEPARTMENT' 
AND C3.CODE_ID(+) = ALLRESULT.PAY_CURRENCY 
AND C3.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = 'CURRENCY'  ORDER BY ALLRESULT.P_ID,ALLRESULT.PAY_CURRENCY
```

[image]

Comment: @jHilscher     help me regarding this

Comment: Please format your query code and put it in some more readable and editable version and try to explain, what you actually want and what you have troubles with. Also, might be nice to show us, what you'd already tried.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist NVL (C2.CODE_CATEGORY, 'N/A') DEPARTMENT column value i am not getting so what to add in condition so that i can get it.

Answer (score 2):

Reformatted your `JPG` query version to some more readable format:

```
SELECT
    ALLRESULT.P_ID EMP_ID
    ,ALLRESULT.EMP_NAME
    ,NVL(C2.CODE_CATEGORY, 'N/A') DEPARTMENT
    ,ALLRESULT.BANK_CODE
    ,NVL(C1.CODE_DESC, 'N/A') BANK_NAME
    ,ALLRESULT.BANK_ACCT
    ,ALLRESULT.VALUE
    ,NVL(C3.CODE_DESC, 'N/A') CURRENCY
    ,ALLRESULT.ID
FROM
    HRIS_CODE_SETUP C1
    ,HRIS_CODE_SETUP C2
    ,HRIS_CODE_SETUP C3
    ,(
        SELECT
            NVL(PAY_EMP.BANK_ACCNAME, 'NA') AS EMP_NAME
            ,PAY_EMP.DEPARTMENT DEPT_ID
            ,NVL(PAY_EMP.BANKNAME, 'NA') BANK_CODE
            ,NVL(PAY_EMP.BANK_ACCT,'NA') BANK_ACCT
            ,PAY_EMP.ID
            ,GROUPSUM.*
        FROM
            PAY_EMP
            ,(
                SELECT
                    RESULT.P_ID
                    ,RESULT.COM_ID
                    -- This can be replaced by more readable CASE statement presented below
                    -- ,SUM(
                        -- DECODE(PAYTYPE
                            -- ,0,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,1,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,2,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,3,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,4,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,5,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,6,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,7,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,12,LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,8,-1*LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,9,-1*LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,10,-1*LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                            -- ,11,-1*LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY)
                        -- )
                    -- ) VALUE
                    SUM(LTAROUND((RESULT.VALUE*B.RATE),C.PROUND,C.ACCURACY) * CASE WHEN PAYTYPE IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12) THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) VALUE
                    -- the SUM above is way easier to read and maintain, isn't it?
                    ,RESULT.PAY_CURRENCY
                FROM
                    PAY_RESULT RESULT
                    ,PAY_CURRENCY B
                    ,V_APPLYITEM2 C
                    ,EPAY_COMPANY D
                WHERE
                    B.COMID = RESULT.COMID
                    AND B.BATCH = RESULT.BATCH
                    AND RESULT.BATCH IN ()
                    AND B.PAYYEAR=RESULT.PAYYEAR 
                    AND B.PAYMONTH = RESULT.PAYMONTH 
                    AND C.PAYITEM_ID=RESULT.PAYITEM
                    AND C.COMP_ID = RESULT.COMID 
                    AND RESULT.COMID = D.PEID 
                    AND RESULT.PAY_CURRENCY = B.C1
                    AND B.C2 = D.PAY_CURRENCY AND (
                            (
                                RESULT.PAYTYPE IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12)
                                AND RESULT.PAY_MODE = 1
                                AND RESULT.PID IS NOT NULL
                                OR LOWER(RESULT.PAYITEM) IN ('BASICPAY','BACKPAY')
                            )
                            OR (RESULT.PAYTYPE IN (8,9,10,11))
                        )
                    AND RESULT.COMID = 'P00000001882-001-SG'
                    AND RESULT.PAYYEAR = 2015
                    AND RESULT.PAYMONTH = 9
                GROUP BY
                    RESULT.PID
                    ,RESULT.COMID
                    ,RESULT.PAY_CURRENCY
            ) GROUPSUM
        WHERE
            PAY_EMP.PAY_METHOD = 1
            AND PAY_EMP.P_ID(+) = GROUPSUM.P_ID
            AND PAY_EMP.COMPANY(+) = GROUPSUM.COMID
    ) ALLRESULT
WHERE
    C1.CODE_ID(+) = ALLRESULT.BANK_CODE
    AND C1.CODE_CATEGORY = 'BANK'
    AND C2.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = ALLRESULT.DEPT_ID
    AND C2.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = 'DEPARTMENT'
    AND C3.CODE_ID(+) = ALLRESULT.PAY_CURRENCY
    AND C3.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = 'CURRENCY'
ORDER BY
    ALLRESULT.P_ID
    ,ALLRESULT.PAY_CURRENCY
```

Now, please answer, what do you mean by `what to add so that i can fetch department column value`?

If you mean the below:

```
SELECT
    ...
    ,NVL(C2.CODE_CATEGORY, 'N/A') DEPARTMENT
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    ...
    AND C2.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = ALLRESULT.DEPT_ID
    AND C2.CODE_CATEGORY(+) = 'DEPARTMENT'
    ...
```

then you must've noticed, you've got `OUTER JOIN` over here, thus `ALLRESULT.DEPT_ID` does not have to be in `C2` table in `CODE_CATEGORY` column (`ALLRESULT` has particular `DEPT_ID` while `C2` doesn't).

Comment: in hris_code_setup table i dont have column as Code,however i do have column named as code_id.

Comment: If you'd written the query (not just sending some JPG image), we would've avoid this problem. Spending my time and rewriting your query from that image I made a mistake. Looks like the column name is `CODE_CATEGORY`, but it doesn't change the fact, that you're using `OUTER JOIN` there and simply might not have such value in your `HRIS_CODE_SETUP ` table.